# Call ArcGIS Server Buffer command without using SOM

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-rest-api

I wanted to see what the best way was of calling the geometry service to carry out a Buffer operation on ArcGIS Server 10, without using the SOM.  Ideally I want to consume the REST API, using a wrapper so that it was easy to call from c#.

Is the GISClient the way forward?  From what I can determine, it looks like you only get stateless (and thus low footprint) access to the Mapserver and Geocode services.

I know that I could construct a call using a URL, but I wondered if there was C# API that wrapped the REST API for you.

Comment: I've always used RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) for these kinds of tasks.

Comment: Is using the [SOAP API endpoint](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Geometry/GeometryServer?wsdl) an option?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you would want to write something of your own when you could use the built in geometry service.  Here is a sample of that in action: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/util_buffergraphic.html